# Buildozer fails to build apk

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build an apk out of a simple kivy python file however I get this error when using the command "buildozer -v android debug" to build the apk.

I'm running on a Ubuntu virtual machine, java jdk is version 8 something, I was using version 14 earlier, but saw some post talking about needing version 8. Not entirely sure though if it was for the same problem that I'm facing.

```
    [INFO]:    *** PYTHON PACKAGE / PROJECT INSTALL STAGE ***
[INFO]:    The requirements (certifi) don't have recipes, attempting to install them with pip
[INFO]:    If this fails, it may mean that the module has compiled components and needs a recipe.
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/tanel/Desktop/python_projects/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build
[INFO]:    -> running python3 -m venv venv
[INFO]:    Upgrade pip to latest version
[INFO]:    -> running bash -c source venv/bin/activate && pip install -U pip
[INFO]:    Install Cython in case one of the modules needs it to build                                  
[INFO]:    -> running bash -c venv/bin/pip install Cython
           working: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a prob...(and 230 more) Exception in thread background thread for pid 39917:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 1637, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 2561, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 2265, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 865, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'

  STDOUT:
Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting Cython
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                      
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/tanel/Desktop/python_projects/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1260, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/tanel/Desktop/python_projects/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/tanel/Desktop/python_projects/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 709, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/tanel/Desktop/python_projects/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/tanel/Desktop/python_projects/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 213, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/tanel/Desktop/python_projects/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 600, in build_recipes
    run_pymodules_install(
  File "/home/tanel/Desktop/python_projects/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 778, in run_pymodules_install
    shprint(sh.bash, '-c', (
  File "/home/tanel/Desktop/python_projects/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 911, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 841, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 865, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'

  STDOUT:
Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting Cython
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/tanel/Desktop/python_projects/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/ubuntu:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1692,unix/ubuntu:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1692'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1584'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     PWD = '/home/tanel/Desktop/python_projects'
#     LOGNAME = 'tanel'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/tanel'
#     USERNAME = 'tanel'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6003'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/7d712013_d467_4bda_a2bd_b92331672047'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '810701175cba4fcd9c9c27ff91c0cc23'
#     MANAGERPID = '1406'
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'tanel'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.103'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=a754c6f3e73fa19690c10fde602798b6'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:50673'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/tanel/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/tanel/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=a754c6f3e73fa19690c10fde602798b6'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/tanel/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/tanel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/tanel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

buildozer.spec file:

```
[app]
    
    # (str) Title of your application
    title = My Application
    
    # (str) Package name
    package.name = myapp
    
    # (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
    package.domain = org.test
    
    # (str) Source code where the main.py live
    source.dir = .
    
    # (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
    source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas
    
    # (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
    #source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png
    
    # (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
    #source.exclude_exts = spec
    
    # (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
    #source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv
    
    # (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
    #source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg
    
    # (str) Application versioning (method 1)
    version = 0.1
    
    # (str) Application versioning (method 2)
    # version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
    # version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py
    
    # (list) Application requirements
    # comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
    requirements = python3,kivy
    
    # (str) Custom source folders for requirements
    # Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
    # requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy
    
    # (str) Presplash of the application
    #presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png
    
    # (str) Icon of the application
    #icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png
    
    # (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
    orientation = portrait
    
    # (list) List of service to declare
    #services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY
    
    #
    # OSX Specific
    #
    
    #
    # author = © Copyright Info
    
    # change the major version of python used by the app
    osx.python_version = 3
    
    # Kivy version to use
    osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1
    
    #
    # Android specific
    #
    
    # (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
    fullscreen = 0
    
    # (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
    # Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
    # red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
    # darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
    # olive, purple, silver, teal.
    #android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF
    
    # (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
    # see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
    # for general documentation.
    # Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
    #android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"
    
    # (list) Permissions
    #android.permissions = INTERNET
    
    # (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
    #android.features = android.hardware.usb.host
    
    # (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
    #android.api = 27
    
    # (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
    #android.minapi = 21
    
    # (int) Android SDK version to use
    #android.sdk = 20
    
    # (str) Android NDK version to use
    #android.ndk = 19b
    
    # (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
    #android.ndk_api = 21
    
    # (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
    #android.private_storage = True
    
    # (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
    #android.ndk_path =
    
    # (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
    #android.sdk_path =
    
    # (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
    #android.ant_path =
    
    # (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
    # This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
    # when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
    # android.skip_update = False
    
    # (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
    # agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
    # the default, you will be shown the license when first running
    # buildozer.
    # android.accept_sdk_license = False
    
    # (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
    #android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity
    
    # (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
    # android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    
    # (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
    #android.whitelist =
    
    # (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
    #android.whitelist_src =
    
    # (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
    #android.blacklist_src =
    
    # (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
    # their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
    # down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
    # OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
    #android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar
    
    # (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
    # directory containing the files)
    #android.add_src =
    
    # (list) Android AAR archives to add
    #android.add_aars =
    
    # (list) Gradle dependencies to add
    #android.gradle_dependencies =
    
    # (list) add java compile options
    # this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
    # see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
    # android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"
    
    # (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
    # please enclose in double quotes 
    # e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
    #android.add_gradle_repositories =
    
    # (list) packaging options to add 
    # see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
    # can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
    # please enclose in double quotes 
    # e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
    #android.add_packaging_options =
    
    # (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
    #android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity
    
    # (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
    # If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
    #android.ouya.category = GAME
    
    # (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
    #android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png
    
    # (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
    #android.manifest.intent_filters =
    
    # (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
    #android.manifest.launch_mode = standard
    
    # (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
    #android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
    #android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
    #android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
    #android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
    #android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so
    
    # (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
    # Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
    #android.wakelock = False
    
    # (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
    #android.meta_data =
    
    # (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
    # project.properties automatically.)
    #android.library_references =
    
    # (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
    #android.uses_library =
    
    # (str) Android logcat filters to use
    #android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D
    
    # (str) Android additional adb arguments
    #android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal
    
    # (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
    #android.copy_libs = 1
    
    # (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
    android.arch = armeabi-v7a
    
    # (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
    # this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
    # android.numeric_version = 1
    
    # (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
    android.allow_backup = True
    
    # (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
    # android.backup_rules =
    
    # (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
    # you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
    # This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
    # Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
    # android.manifest_placeholders = [:]
    
    #
    # Python for android (p4a) specific
    #
    
    # (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
    #p4a.fork = kivy
    
    # (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
    #p4a.branch = master
    
    # (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
    #p4a.source_dir =
    
    # (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
    #p4a.local_recipes =
    
    # (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
    #p4a.hook =
    
    # (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
    # p4a.bootstrap = sdl2
    
    # (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
    #p4a.port =
    
    # Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
    # "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
    # Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
    # NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
    # setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
    #p4a.setup_py = false
    
    
    #
    # iOS specific
    #
    
    # (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
    #ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
    # Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
    ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
    ios.kivy_ios_branch = master
    
    # Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
    # Uncomment to use a custom checkout
    #ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
    # Or specify URL and branch
    ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
    ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0
    
    # (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
    ios.codesign.allowed = false
    
    # (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
    # Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
    #ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"
    
    # (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
    #ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s
    
    
    [buildozer]
    
    # (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
    log_level = 2
    
    # (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
    warn_on_root = 1
    
    # (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
    # build_dir = ./.buildozer
    
    # (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
    # bin_dir = ./bin
    
    #    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #    List as sections
    #
    #    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
    #    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
    #    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
    #    Instead of doing:
    #
    #[app]
    #source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
    #
    #    This can be translated into:
    #
    #[app:source.exclude_patterns]
    #license
    #data/audio/*.wav
    #data/images/original/*
    #
    
    
    #    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #    Profiles
    #
    #    You can extend section / key with a profile
    #    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
    #    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
    #    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
    #
    #[app@demo]
    #title = My Application (demo)
    #
    #[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
    #images/hd/*
    #
    #    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
    #
    #buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Comment: It apparently doesn't like that your folder name `python projects` has a space in its name.

Comment: Yeah, sorry bout that, I saw it just after I posted it, I fixed it and tried it again, however it stil gives me an error (edited to show the new error)

Comment: can you show your `buildozer.spec` file? I guess you have entered `ctypes` there which is a built-in module and need not be entered in requirements.

Comment: @AnkitSangwan I added the .spec file, didn't see ctypes in there though

Comment: @Tostuk Install the libffi-dev package using `sudo apt install libffi-dev` in your Virtual machine then delete the .buildozer directory and rerun buildozer

Comment: @AnkitSangwan I installed libffi-dev and deleted .buildoser dir and tried it again but I still got an error, I updated the post to show the new error

Comment: @Tostuk is this your first app? Have you followed the steps given in [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#targeting-android)?

Comment: Anyway run the command `sudo apt install libssl-dev`. Go to the [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#targeting-android) and make sure you have everything installed. As I can see you didn't have `libffi-dev` earlier and now `libssl-dev`. So you might be missing more

Comment: @AnkitSangwan It is my first one. I need to quickly make the easiest app that reads BLE characteristics, but I don't know which solution would be best, i had some problems using Android Studio with kotlin aswell. I followed the steps on kivy's guide https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html

Comment: Run the following command `sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev` and then this one `pip3 install --upgrade Cython==0.29.19 virtualenv`. It will make sure you have everything installed. And not get such error again

Comment: @AnkitSangwan I got it working now, thank you!

Comment: @Tostuk No Problem! Lemme just add it in the answer so that others can see it too

Comment: @Tostuk if you are satisfied with answer mind accepting it so that others can see it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing `libffi-dev` earlier and now you are missing `libssl-dev`. Looks like you might be missing other requirements for buildozer too. Follow the steps given in buildozer [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#targeting-android)

Open your terminal and run following commands:

```
sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev
pip3 install --upgrade Cython==0.29.19 virtualenv
```

Then re-run buildozer.